# Can a node belong to multiple menus?

Tags: routes

I have a few pages such as a general "contact us" page. I'd like this page to exist inside of the Main Menu but be able to be linked from other menus (Theatre menu, for example). I create the contact us page and assign it to the Main menu on the node's form. Then, I add the link from the Theatre menu.

However, the contact us page now shows the Theatre menu.

How do I accomplish linking a page from multiple menus but keeping it inside of it's own menu?

I thought the old convention was to add existing links such as `http:/learn/contact_us`. If I add the link `learn/contact_us` to Theatre's menu, the Contact us page now shows the Theatre menu (instead of the Main menu).

Additional folks running across this problem:
https://drupal.org/node/1314742

Comment: Can you not add the menu items manually and just point both at "contact us" page???

Comment: It seems that if I add this page to the Theatre menu for example. Upon viewing the page, the Theatre menu is now rendered on the page instead of the Main menu.

Comment: Perhaps the menu is not being removed in the block management settings??? Sorry I am having a hard time comprehending what the exact issue is without seeing what your doing

Comment: If you want to create 2 menu items linked to the same node at different levels of a menu. When you'll try to view the node only one menu trail will be active. So the breadcrumb for example will always be the same. You may take a look at [NodeSymlinks](https://drupal.org/project/nodesymlinks)

Comment: Alex, no worries. I appreciate the questions. DnBase, thanks. I just came across multiple_node_menu that looks similar and giving it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the project [menu token](https://drupal.org/project/menu_token) allowed me to find a good work around. I set it up as pictured below. By using the token [site:url] followed by an existing path, a effectively have a link to an existing node ***without changing the existing nodes current parent menu.***

[image]